# Is it in the Gluon API to keep our app in Portrait Mode even if the user rotates their device in Landscape Mode?

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

After styling my app in portrait mode, I've discovered its layout is not acceptable should the user manipulate their phone to invoke the app into landscape mode. I can put in the time later to rewrite/retest the UX for both portrait and landscape mode, but for the time being is the a way for us to have our app hold portrait mode all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API or Attach service for this yet.
However you can modify the AndroidManifest.xml file (Android) or the Default-Info.plist file (iOS) to force one single orientation, instead of the existing portrait and landscape ones.

**Android**

See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_android_2 for reference.

The AndroidManifest.xml file is generated for the project with the gluonfx:package goal, and it is available at target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gensrc/android.

Copy this file to `src/android` and make any modification needed:

- Portrait

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' package='$your_package' android:versionCode='1' android:versionName='1.0'>
    <application android:label='$your_label' android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity'
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             <intent-filter>
                <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
                <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

- Landscape

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' package='$your_package' android:versionCode='1' android:versionName='1.0'>
    <application android:label='$your_label' android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity' 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
             <intent-filter>
                <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
                <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

Then run again `gluonfx:package`, the final manifest will contain the changes.

**iOS**

See for reference https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_ios_2.

The configuration is defined by the keys `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations-ipad`. By default with values:

```
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
```

Add the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/substrate/ios/Partial-Info.plist` and include this code:

- Portrait

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- Landscape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>         
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `mvn gluonfx:link` again, the final plist will contain these changes.